# Upside-Down Number Problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle

These are numbers that can also be read upside down as the same number, or different number: 0, 1, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 18, so on. Each number can only be used once.

<strike>Using these numbers, try to get all numbers from 1-100.</strike>

**EDIT: 1-100 has been completed by Marius, so keep going if you want to...**

Here are 1 to 5 so you can understand.

1: 1

2: 8 - 6

3: 9 - 6

4: 10 - 6

5: 6 - 1

Comment: did you delete the part saying we cannot use a number twice? if so we can do everything with 1+1+...

Comment: do you mean each number, or each digit? e.g. is 11 valid?

Comment: I'll allow that, also I added that to the original post.

Comment: Why not 2 and 5? If we are talking traditional digital displays here, those two are definitely paired and ought to be included. Even handwritten, they can look quite similar when rotated.

Comment: I was going to do that but there would be too many numbers, so I just decided to make it numbers that are upside-down in the font of the website. 1 isn't perfect but I allowed it anyways @feelinferrety

Comment: Faraz, just to be clear, is this a question you made up or did you find it somewhere else? If you found it somewhere else, please edit the question to add proper attribution. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I made this question myself. I have added attribution in all questions that I have found in other places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love these puzzles.

$0 = 0$
$1 = 1$
$2 = 11-9$
$3 = 11 -8$
$4 = 10 - 6$
$7 = 1+6$
$8 = 8$
$9 = 9$
$10 = 10$
$11 = 11$
$12 = 11 + 1$
$13 = 6+8-1$
$14 = 6+8$
$15 = 6+8+1$
$16 = 16$
$17 = 16+1$
$18 = 18$
$19 = 19$
$20 = 10 + 9 + 1$
$21 = 10 + 11$
$22 = 10 + 11 + 1$
$23 = 16 + 8 - 1$
$24 = 16 + 8$
$25 = 16 + 8 + 1$
$26 = 10 + 16$
$27 = 11 + 16$
$28 = 11 + 16 + 1$
$29 = 19 + 10$
$30 = 10 + 19 + 1$
$31 = 11 + 19 + 1$
$32 = 18 + 8 + 6$
$33 = 18 + 8 + 6  +1$
$34 = 19 + 16 - 1$
$35 = 19 + 16$
$36 = 19 + 16 + 1$
$37 = 10 + 11 + 16$
$38 = 1 + 10 + 11 + 16$
$39 = 18 + 11 + 10$
$40 = 18 + 11 + 10 + 1$
$41 = 61 + 1 - 10 - 11$
$42 = 61 - 19$
$43 = 61 - 19 + 1$
$44 = 1 + 6 + 10 + 11 + 16$
$45 = 8 + 10 + 11 + 16$
$46 = 1 + 8 + 10 + 11 + 16$
$47 = 61 - 8 - 6$
$48 = 61 + 1 - 8 - 6$
$49 = 9 + 10 + 11 + 19$
$50 = 1 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 19$
$51 = 61 - 10$
$52 = 61 + 1 - 10$
$53 = 61 - 8$
$54 = 61 - 8 + 1$
$55 = 61 - 6$
$56 = 61 - 6 + 1$
$57 = 61 - 9 + 6 - 1$
$58 = 61 - 9 + 6$
$59 = 61 - 8 + 6$
$60 = 61 - 1$
$61 = 61$
$62 = 61 + 1$
$63 = 61 + 9 - 6 - 1$
$64 = 61 + 9 - 6$
$65 = 61 + 9 - 6 + 1$
$66 = 61 + 6 - 1$
$67 = 61 + 6$
$68 = 68$
$69 = 69$
$70 = 69 + 1$
$71 = 61 + 10$
$72 = 81 - 9$
$73 = 61 + 11 + 1$
$74 = 68 + 6$
$75 = 81 - 6$
$76 = 81 - 6 + 1$
$77 = 61 + 10 + 6$
$78 = 81 - 9 + 6$
$79 = 81 + 9 - 11$
$80 = 81 - 1$
$81 = 81$
$82 = 81 + 1$
$83 = 81 - 6 + 8$
$84 = 81 - 6 + 9 $
$85 = 81 + 10 - 4$
$86 = 86$
$87 = 88 - 1$
$88 = 88$
$89 = 89$
$90 = 91 - 1$
$91 = 91$
$92 = 91 + 1$
$93 = 81 + 11 + 1$
$94 = 96 - 8 + 6$
$95 = 96 - 1$
$96 = 96$
$97 = 96 + 1$
$98 = 98$
$99 = 99$
$100 = 99 + 1$

Comment: given other answers, I believe the question was not narrowly enough defined, but as I understand it, your answer is a possible one

Comment: Good job, I edited the original post incase anyone wanted to keep going.

Comment: $25 = 16+8−1$ ?

Comment: But who would be so pedantic to check all of these anyway?

Comment: @FlorianF. Thanks for the heads up. Obviously that should be +1 not -1. Do the rest check out? :)

Comment: 95 and 96 still need some work.

Comment: @FlorianF. Fixed. Thanks for checking everything. I owe you one cold beverage of your choice.

Comment: There are more mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

Here are answers for all numbers in the range 0 to 249.

0 to 9 are:

> 0 = 0
>
> 1 = 1
>
> 2 = 8-6
>
> 3 = 9-6
>
> 4 = 9-6+1
>
> 5 = 6-1
>
> 6 = 6
>
> 7 = 6+1
>
> 8 = 8
>
> 9 = 9

For the rest, do this:

> To these numbers you can add up to four multiples of ten expressed as (91-81), (96-86), (98-88) and (99-89), so it is then trivial to get any number in the range 0 to 49.
>  
> By adding multiples of fifty, expressed as (61-11), (66-16), (68-18), or (69-19) to these you get all numbers up to 249.

Comment: Can we really flip '90' to '06'? (moot point, since you could still use e.g. 86-66 to get 20), and 61 would still be valid to open up everything above 60.

Comment: That is a good point. The OP lists 10 as a reversible number, so I just assumed that 60, 80, 90 would be fine too. I'll edit my answer slightly.

Comment: Any number that can be read upside-down can be used. Either the original one or the upside-down one

Answer (score 5):

There only 5 numbers which can be used upside down. 0,1,6,8 and 9.

> You can use any function

Ok then,

> $$0=\log_ \frac 18 (\log_ 6 (((\sqrt9)!))$$
>
> $$1=\log_ \frac 18 (\log_ 6 ((\sqrt{{\sqrt{\sqrt{(\sqrt9)!}}}})))$$
>
> $$2=\log_ \frac 18 (\log_ 6 (\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{{\sqrt{(\sqrt9)!)}}}}}}})$$

Keep adding sqrts over the sqrt(9)! to make all the other numbers. You also can add + 0 to use all the numbers.

Comment: Good job, nice loophole. I checked it because it's correct, though it kind of defeats the purpose (I don't really care though)

Comment: How do you get 1/2 from 0, 1, 8?

Comment: Sorry, I will change the typo

Comment: (You needn't accept the first "correct" answer given - you're welcome to accept whatever answer best exemplifies the solution you envisioned.  And of course you're free to change your Accepted answer at any time. Not to take anything away from Allan's solution, but it seems that [@Jaap Scherphuis' answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56162/30633) is more in line with what you were looking for, and there's no reason you couldn't accept that answer instead.)

Answer (score 2):

0, 1, 6, 8, 9 are given.

- 2 = 8 - 6
- 3 = 9 - 6
- 4 = 10 - 6
- 5 = 6 - 1
- 7 = 6 + 1
- 11 = 9 + 8 - 6
- 12 = 9 + 8 - 6 + 1
- 13 = 10 + 9 - 6
- 14 = 8 + 6
- 15 = 8 + 6 + 1
- 16
- 17 = 9 + 8
- 18
- 19
- 20 = 160 / 8
- 21 = 19 + 8 - 6
- 22 = 90 - 68
- 23 = 91 - 68
- 24 = 16 + 8
- 25 = 16 + 9
- 27 = 18 + 9
- 28 = 89 - 61
- 29 = 90 - 61
- 30 = 180 / 6
- 36 = 16 R * 9 (R is the square root key, common in most simple calculators)
- 37 = 98 - 61
- 38 = 98 - 60

Not found (yet): 26, 31 to 35, 39 and above

Comment: Oh, I seem to have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Siddhartha No problem, I edited it as it might not have been clear.

Answer (score 1):

**OP Edit: Understood the question wrong.**

Numbers which are also numbers upside down:
$0, 1, 6, 8, 9,$

Hence, there are $5 + 4*5 = 25$ such numbers, all of which can be generated using a simple program.

Here are the numbers:
1 6 8 9 10 11 16 18 19 60 61 66 68 69 80 81 86 88 89 90 91 96 98 99 100

Comment: I may have explained it badly. I edited it, read it again.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jose's answer:

- 20 = 80 - 60
- 22 = 88 - 66
- 23 = 89 - 66
- 24 = 96 / (9 - 6 + 1)
- 25 = 100 / (10 - 6)
- 26 = 86 - 60
- 27 = 88 - 61
- 28 = 88 - 60
- 29 = 89 - 60
- 30 = 100 / (11 - 6) + 9 + 1

Comment: I think the idea is to generate all numbers from 1 to 100, not only the upside down ones, with expressions that only use upside down numbers. For example, 5 = 6 − 1. (But maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: I expected to use each digit only once. Is that right? Otherwise, there is a trivial solution: 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1.

Comment: I've just asked OP. I don't know if we can use each digit once, or each number once?

Comment: Sorry, when I edited it I forgot to add that back. Yes, each number can only be used once.

Comment: Can we use calculator key shorthands? Keying `=` repeats the last operation. For instance, `3+4=` gives 7, `3+4==` gives 11, `3+4===` gives 15, and so on. If so, parenthesis are forbidden, since common calculators don't have them.